# Need Css Selector with attribute containing special escape (apostrophe) character

Tags: jquery, attributes, jquery-selectors

I'm trying use a jQuery css selector to find an element using an attribute specification. The problem is that sometimes the attribute's value contains an apostrophe, like this:

```
<ul id="mylist">
    <li data-abrv="N">None</li>
    <li data-abrv="W'A">With'Apos</li>
</ul>
```

I've tried

`$('#mylist li[data-abrv="W'A"]')`

and

`$('#mylist li[data-abrv="W\'A"]')`

...but neither seems to work. Is this possible? If so, how?

Note: I cannot control the HTML content.

Comment: That should work: `$('#mylist li[data-abrv="W\'A"]').html()`. So not sure what is your issue?!  EDIT: see it: http://jsfiddle.net/rsj8Lzwv/

Comment: I concur. The snippet in which you're escaping the single quote should work. Check to see if another less obvious part of the selector is broken. For example, maybe the ID is not unique in the DOM.

Comment: This question missing some context, e.g, **how** do you call this code? Maybe you are just calling it ***before*** specific element is available in the DOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work.

```js
$('#mylist li[data-abrv="W\'A"]').css({color:'red'});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="mylist">
    <li data-abrv="N">None</li>
    <li data-abrv="W'A">With'Apos</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I can't argue with it working here. @@AWolff is probably right that  the context of the call is probably the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#mylist li[data-abrv*="\'"]')
```

see [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/j6gc5zja/) by this selector you can select all li which data-abrv contains ' single cot

Comment: Really doesn't sound like expected behaviour and BTW, why OP's code isn't working?

Comment: The OP is not looking to select a specific element, not all elements containing a single quote in that attribute.